# How to fetch details using criteria query in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

We have two tables `student` and `mark`. We can join these tables with `studentid`  in a normal `select` query:

```
select * from student st,mark mk where st.studentId=mk.studentId
```

How can I create a criteria query to fetch the details?

The entity class for Student is:

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "student")
    public class Student{
    private int studentId;
    private String name;

      @Column(name = "studentId")
      public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
      }

      public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
      }

      @Column(name = "name")
      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }
    }
```

The entity class for Mark is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mark")
public class Mark{
private int markId;
private int studentId;
private String name;
private String mark

  @Column(name = "markId")
  public int getMarkId() {
    return markId;
  }

  public void setMarkId(String markId) {
    this.markId = markId;
  }

  @Column(name = "studentId")
  public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
  }

  public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
  }

  @Column(name = "markId")
  public int getMarkId() {
    return markId;
  }

  public void setMarkId(String markId) {
    this.markId = markId;
  }

  @Column(name = "name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

 @Column(name = "mark")
  public String getMark() {
    return mark;
  }

  public void setMark(String mark) {
    this.mark = mark;
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't Mark be mapped as a List in Student, using @OneToMany? Also, Student should be mapped in Mark using @ManytoOne.

Comment: Where is the JPA Criteria code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is an *Object* Relational Mapping tool. You map relationships between objects in your Java code.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "student")
    public class Student{
    private int studentId;
    private String name;
    private Set<Mark> marks; 

      @Column(name = "studentId")
      public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
      }

      public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
      }

      @Column(name = "name")
      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
      public Set<Student> getStudents(){
        return students;
      }
    }
```

Mark:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mark")
public class Mark{
private int markId;
private Student student;
private String name;
private String mark

  @Column(name = "markId")
  public int getMarkId() {
    return markId;
  }

  public void setMarkId(String markId) {
    this.markId = markId;
  }

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "studentId")
  public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
  }

  public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
  }

  @Column(name = "markId")
  public int getMarkId() {
    return markId;
  }

  public void setMarkId(String markId) {
    this.markId = markId;
  }

  @Column(name = "name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

 @Column(name = "mark")
  public String getMark() {
    return mark;
  }

  public void setMark(String mark) {
    this.mark = mark;
  }
}
```